# Dynamically creating TableViews on click of button

Tags: javascript

Let me come out very clear. I have some buttons in my Model Window.

```
    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:50});

    var row2 = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
    height:'auto'
    });

    row2.add(Button);
    row2.add(Image);

    var data = [row,row2];
    var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data:data
   });
```

I want 7 TextField dynamically in the first row. The second row remains static but the first one should grow

Comment: ?? i have no idea what that means. what extactly do you want to do. can u paste a demo of what you have into jsfiddle?

Comment: The function returns many row Object,  and i need to access each object...

Comment: no idea. i have no idea what the object looks like, can you make a fiddle?

Comment: How to use jsfiddle and what should i place there

Comment: This is what it returns for row object [Ti.UI.TableViewRow]

Comment: You're not calling addRow() at all. Variable row is never assigned (besides inside addRow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to make an array to be used to create a TableView? Then do something like

```
function addRow(txtField) {
  var tf = Titanium.UI.createTextField({width:100,height:30,hintText:txtField});
  var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:50});
  row.add(rf);
  return row;
}

array[0] = addRow('Textfield 1');
array[1] = addRow('Textfield 2');
array[2] = addRow('Textfield 3');

Ti.UI.createTableView({data:array});
```

Comment: Updated my question... let me try u r code too... thanks a lot, i am struck for 5 hrs in this....

Comment: Sorry, i just updated my entire working code... you can test it... i want to add TableView on the click on buttons each time

Comment: @theJava: You should keep the problem description in your question. I for example have no idea what your question is about.

Comment: @theJava your code grows larger by each edit without any substantial new information. If you want us to look into it in more detail please extract the relevant parts and post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).